# How can I not use duplicate verbs in the same sentence?

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence:

> It seems that solitary life may serve the statue - quo preserving inertia whereas joining social life does one become aware of his/her full potential

Should I repeat the phrase:

> ...whereas joining social life may serve...

or should I leave as it is?

Comment: Hi the phrase is status quo, not statue que. Also "joining social life does one become aware" is not grammatically correct.

Comment: thank you, my question actually is about if I can replace "may" with "does" in order to avoid duplication..? I serve you while you do me (while you serve me).. or I may serve you while you do serve me (here do as "may") ??

Comment: If you make another question asking this, and also link to any research you've done to find out the answer, I'm sure you'll receive some nice replies, and the question will not be closed. Your latest comment asks a specific question, so you just need to explain where your confusion lies with the question, and include any research you've done and repost this as a new question (if you haven't already).

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple grammar problems in this sentence: parallelism, missing comma, and word choice issues. I've cleaned it up as best I can while retaining your general phrasing. I hope in the cleaned up form, you can see the answer to your question about duplicate verbs.

**"It seems that by living alone one may preserve the status-quo, whereas by joining social life one becomes aware of his/her full potential."**

Comment: I would also generally replace "his/her" with "one's" if I'm already using "one" as a pronoun earlier in the sentence.

Comment: thank you, my question actually is about if I can replace "may" with "does" in order to avoid duplication..? I serve you while you do me (while you serve me).. or I may serve you while you do serve me (here do as "may") ??

Comment: You should repeat the verb. It is the repetition that matches the cadence an English ear will expect to hear.  "I serve you while you serve me." and "I may serve you while you serve me." and "I may serve you while you may serve me."